# How to deal with 45deg angles and sqrt2 multiples?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to make modular walls. It's working fine, except that I wanted to make 45degree angled walls too. If my wall is X units in size, the 45 degree wall, must be square root of 2, times X (as it is the hypotenuse of a square with side X units).

What can I do about that? I'm very afraid of using floating point numbers, as they introduce errors, that can add up and misalign the grid.

Comment: Presumably the vertices will still have integer coordinates, so you could try snapping them to the grid.

Comment: I simplified my answer as per a suggestion from @squeamishossifrage. If you've already seen my original answer, have a look at the edited version, which eliminates several steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the edge from where you want to have a wall at an angle. Extrude along one axis by pressing <kbd>E</kbd> then the axis you want to extrude along and typing the distance. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then move along the other axis by the same distance. In the GIF below, I used <kbd>E</kbd> -> <kbd>X</kbd> -> <kbd>2</kbd> -> <kbd>Enter</kbd> to extrude by 2 BU along the X axis then <kbd>G</kbd> -> <kbd>Y</kbd> -> <kbd>2</kbd> -> <kbd>Enter</kbd> to move the new edge by 2 BU along the Y axis.
If the wall gets its normal in the wrong direction, select the face and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to point the normals outwards or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to point the normals inwards.

[image]

Comment: Alternatively, type EX2GY2. Then there are no extra facets to delete.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Of course. I have to blame that overlook on having just up from a nap. I'll edit my answer shortly. Thanks for pointing it out.